# Why is the Designer in Codename one not reporting the attributes I set?

Tags: codenameone

I started a Codename One project with the "Hello World bare bones". I used to define the styles in the Theme tab from the Designer but now it is becoming tedious.

Actually for some selectors, even if I override (unchecking the `Derive` box) some properties the style is not changed in the Designer (see below) or in the app itself.

[image: The background should be black]

[image: The text should be centered]

However, in the list of selectors, the color is not the one I selected but the alignment seems to be it.

[image: Radio button has the expected alignment but not the expected background color]

It seems that the theme is locked somewhere. Do I make a mistake, or should I set a constant to "unlock" the theme, or even should I clear some directories?

Please note that I am using NetBeans with designer V 1.1

[image: Designer version 1.1].

**Edit March 1st 2017**

Following @Diamond's great tips, I was able to change the foreground color by setting the Border to empty (instead of NULL). However now the alignment is still not what I expect (see below). How can I do for this property ?

[image: Even after setting the Border to empty the alignment property does not seem to be taken into account]

Any help appreciated,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Designer, **Border** is superior to **background color** and **background image**. Which means if the **border image** is set, a **background color** will have no effect unless the border is just a stroke or line.

Always solve this with these few steps:

1. Go to the Border tab and uncheck the override.
2. Click the `...` button next to `Border Help` and a new Dialog will show.
3. Change the `Type` (First line) to `Empty` and click `Ok`.

Your background color will now have an effect.

Comment: Wow you should be awarded a medal @Diamond! This is a great tip. Actually now my properties are applied at least for some background / foreground colors. I editied my question because for alignment, it does not work as expected (see the screen capture I added). And by the way, which selector would you use to make the hamburger menu black (foreground) ?

Comment: RadioButton UIID cannot be aligned through the designer because of the CheckImage that has to be positioned on either the `Left` or the `Right`. Hamburger menu button is an image which can be changed in the theme `Constants`. The constant to change is `sideMenuImage` and it may require you adding your own image first.

Comment: Oh you're right I remember now about the sideMenuImage I changed in a previous project! Thanks a ton @Diamond!